# Schema 'name' does not exist derby

Tags: java, database, jdbc, schema, derby

It looks like i'm not going further:
I'm trying to start virtual server "programmatically"(in the java file) but i got a *Schema does not exist* message when i run the project

```
public class Giocatori extends javax.swing.JFrame {

  Connection con;
  Connection conn;
  Statement stmt;
  ResultSet rs;
  int curRow=0;


    public Giocatori() {
        initComponents();
      try {
          DoConnect();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(Giocatori.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(Giocatori.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      } catch (Exception ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(Giocatori.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
    }

    public void DoConnect() throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, Exception {
        try {
            NetworkServerControl serverControl = new NetworkServerControl(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"),1527);
            serverControl.start(null);

            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();           
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver());
    String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/db";
    String uName = "username";
    String uPass= "password";
pannellosotto.setVisible(false);
//When the method getConnection is called, the DriverManager will attempt to locate a suitable driver from amongst those 
//loaded at initialization and those loaded explicitly using the same classloader as the current applet or application. 
 con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);

 //Statement: Used to implement simple SQL statements with no parameters.
//PreparedStatement: (Extends Statement.) Used for precompiling SQL statements that might contain input parameters. See Using Prepared Statements for more information.
//CallableStatement: (Extends PreparedStatement.) Used to execute stored procedures that may contain both input and output parameters. See Stored Procedures for more information

 stmt = con.createStatement();
String SQL = "SELECT * From Giocatori";
/*To execute a query, call an execute method from Statement such as the following:

    execute: Returns true if the first object that the query returns is a ResultSet object. 
Use this method if the query could return one or more ResultSet objects. Retrieve the ResultSet 
objects returned from the query by repeatedly calling Statement.getResultSet.
    executeQuery: Returns one ResultSet object.
    executeUpdate: Returns an integer representing the number of rows affected by the SQL statement. 
Use this method if you are using INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE SQL statements */
 rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

 rs.next();
```

The *Schema* **exists**. It is also set as default schema...

Comment: What, precisely, is your question?

Comment: how to fix this problem, i run file and get this message: Schema 'name' does not exist. How do i fix it? That schema exists and is set as default schema, where am i wrong?

Comment: Please include the stacktrace of the exception, and specify which statement triggers that exception.

Comment: i deleted everything, i will start over next days...thank you for your time